# Wavelength of electromagnetic waves

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, wavelength

How can you determine experimentally the wave length of an electromagnetic wave having wave length in the visible range and that in the ultra violet range?

Comment: Use a spectrometer. And show a bit of research effort next time.

Comment: can you be more specified?
*more explanation*

Comment: I mean .. I'm not going to try that experiment, I'm just asking for steps! @ACuriousMind

Comment: Get a prism made of a material with a known index of refraction and see how much the light bends. I think @ACuriousMind's point is that this is a very basic question which can be checked via Google or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_spectrometer).

Comment: Measure its frequency and divide  $c$ by the result.  (with apologies to the joke about how to count all the cows in a herd)

Comment: Spectrometer is not going to give you a value of the wavelength, only relative dispersion. The OP is asking how one can determine the value.

Comment: @H.H.H - No, ACuriousMind does NOT need to be more specific in a comment. You need to stop asking to be spoon-fed ideas. Google "spectrometer", for Heaven's sake.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lacks basic research effort.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about ultraviolet but for visible light if it's monochromatic like a laser then one way to determine the wavelength is to use a wire or a diffraction grading.
Set up A laser and a wire with a diffraction pattern projected onto a screen. If you know the distance from the wire to the screen, The thickness of the wire and then measure the spacing's of the diffraction pattern then you can calculate the wavelength of the light. If you know three of the four then you could calculate the fourth for instance if you know the wavelength and the distances then you can calculate the thickness of the wire.

Comment: Could the down voter  please explain why they think this answers wrong? My answer is common knowledge do you disagree with it or just not understand my description?

Comment: I upvoted. The diffraction angles are a good way to calculate wavelength if the slit dimensions are known. It's a better answer than saying use a spectrometer. Maybe if an explanation was given as to how a spectrometer works, it would be more helpful.

Comment: for the ultraviolet I guess the same procedures can be followed the only difference is that screen would be covered with illuminating highlighter

Comment: This does depend on having a monochromatic, coherent source, though.  Not anywhere near as useful as a calibrated spectrometer.